# Multi-Triggers with Animation

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, triggers, textblock

I have the following `TextBlock` with animation

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding StatusMessage}" 
                  Margin="5,0,0,0" 
                  Foreground="White">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSystemReady, 
                                               NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, 
                                               Mode=OneWay}" 
                             Value="False">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Name="FadeOut">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 From="1.0" 
                                                 To="0.0" 
                                                 Duration="0:0:3.5"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSystemReady, 
                                               NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, 
                                               Mode=OneWay}" 
                             Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="FadeOut" />
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1.0"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <Trigger Property="Opacity" Value="0.0">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Ready"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

The animation works, but when it is finished (i.e. the Opacity of the control is 0.0) I want to return automatically to the ready state after a status message has been shown and elegantly faded away. I am attempting to do this with a standard `Trigger` but this is not firing, **why and how do I fix this?**

Thanks for your time.

Comment: So you want to change `StatusMessage` to `Ready` when the Opacity is 0.0?

Comment: Yes, I want this automatically and I would also like the `StatusMessage` property to change as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Trigger` is not firing because `Opacity` property is still locked by the animation, but you can use an animation to change the `Text` value if you want using a `ObjectAnimation`.

Example:

```
<BeginStoryboard Name="FadeOut">
    <Storyboard >
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1.0"  To="0.0" Duration="0:0:3.5"/>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Text" BeginTime="0:0:3.5" >
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="Ready" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1.0"  To="1.0" BeginTime="0:0:3.5"/>
    </Storyboard>
</BeginStoryboard>
```

However setting the `Text` to `Ready` in the Animation will not set the `StatusMessage` property to `Ready`.

Comment: I would like to update the `StatusMessage` as well, is this possible? Why does my approach above not work? Thanks again for your help...